# Get Comment Reply Link Only?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using comment_reply_link, for the reply links on every comment, but I want to use an image instead of text. I only need the link of the comment reply, not the whole thing. Codex wasn't helpful, neither the WP forums.

```
<span class="reply">
  <a href="<?php //comment reply link here ?>">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/css/images/reply-button.png" alt="" />
  </a>
</span>
```

Comment: So what doesn't work? The image link? What does the resulting page source look like?

Comment: comment_reply_link doesn't return the exact link, but the whole code, including the <a> tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to replace the link text, add the image code as an argument:

```
<?php 
comment_reply_link( array ( 'reply_text' => '<img src="..." alt="Reply">' ) );
?>
```

Otherwise see the [source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1011) for the way the URL is generated.

Comment: Cool, it worked, but I used a CSS solution. Will definitely use this on my next project, thanks again!